# iphone - opening an artist link on an application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

I am trying to open an "artist link" on an iPhone application but it is not working. The link is to be inside a local HTML file.

I have tried to use "http://phobos...." or "itms://...." but it seems to be not working.

Yes, I am aware of [this apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html), but what is written on this doc does not seams to work for artist links.

Before answering generically, try this. Open itunes and make a search for your name. Right click on your name and copy the link. [This is my link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/magno-urbano/id290406205). Use this link inside a local HTML on your app and see if it opens. I cannot get mine to work.

I am using the technique and the methods mentioned on the apple doc to make all the redirections but I see the message CANNOT OPEN ITUNES. (itunes ?)

any clues? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try either one of these instead of copying the link from itunes, just replace the end part of the URL with the relevant artist name.

Artist’s name or App Store developer’s name: http://itunes.com/Artist_Or_Developer_Name

Album name: http://itunes.com/Artist_Name/Album_Name

App Store apps: http://itunes.com/app/App_Name

Movies: http://itunes.com/movie/Movie_Title

TV show: http://itunes.com/tv/Show_Title

Comment: thanx alooooooot boosszsssssssssssssssss